# Android starting intent activity error in service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

In my application, there is a service class. I want to start an intent 10 seconds later with this service. When I try a basic toast message instead of starting intent, it works. However, when I write `startActivity(intent)` an error occurs. Here is my code. Where am I making mistake?

```
public class EkraniKilitle extends Service {

    Handler yardimci;
    Intent kilitEkrani;
    final static long ZAMAN = 10000;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        kilitEkrani = new Intent(EkraniKilitle.this, KilitEkrani.class);

        yardimci = new Handler();
        yardimci.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                servisiDurdur();
                startActivity(kilitEkrani);

            }
        }, ZAMAN);

    }

    public void servisiDurdur() {

        stopService(new Intent(this, EkraniKilitle.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the exact error? Log messages?

Comment: It closes application. The message is: "Unfortunately, CocukTablet has stopped."

Comment: No. I mean the error messages in your LogCat

Comment: Also post the `KilitEkrani` class in addition to the LogCat stack trace. Is `KilitEkrani` declared as an Activity in the manifest, and does it extend Activity?

Comment: Try to first start activity, and then stop your service. Maybe it's a reason.

Comment: Андрей Москвичёв I did it but it didn't change. By the way, how can I log it?

Comment: From the command line type 'adb logcat'. From eclipse go to `Window -> Show View -> logcat`

Comment: 02-17 19:29:42.961: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @halilkaya post the **full** trace (that line in your comment is not helpful at all) as an *edit* to your question.

Comment: it gives this message only

Comment: "it gives this message only" -- no, it does not. At best, that is the end of 10-20 lines, in red.

Comment: check at my answer below , i guess you haven't specified the second activity in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to add your second activity to the `manifest`
after `</activity>` add `<activity android:name=".MySecondClass"/>`

Comment: It doesn't work. Because when I try it in another way, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Call `startActivity(kilitEkrani);` **before** `servisiDurdur();` and to stop your current service all what you need is to call `stopSelf()` you do not have to use `stopService`

Comment: It's something else. Cause I added stopSelf() "later". Without that, it didn't work, too.